# Text in transparent box on top of image?

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with creating a transparent box on top of a background image, like [this](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_transparency). My code is almost exactly the same, but for some reason, I can't get the transparent box to move away from the top of the image (I'd like the box to be centered with some margin above and below). Adding padding:20px to .background does nothing; adding margin:20px to #transbox only increases the left and right margins by 20px, but does nothing to the top and bottom margins.

HTML & CSS:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/5OMTuqOM7bI");
}
#transbox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 60px;
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3C5FA3;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
}
.clearfix:after {
  visibility: hidden;
  display: block;
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix background">
  <div id="transbox">
    <h3>Some text here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `padding: 0 30px;` is identical to `padding-top: 0; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 30px;`

Comment: *Adding `padding: 20px;`  to `.background` does nothing* That's because later in your CSS you overwrite this padding in `.container`.

Answer (score 0):

Several options to get this. One of them is to set the `padding-top/bottom` of the container.

```
padding: 30px;
```

(instead of `padding: 0 30px`).

Here is the fix to your code:

```css
.background {
    background-image:url("https://source.unsplash.com/5OMTuqOM7bI");
}

#transbox {
    background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.8);
    padding:20px;
    margin:60px;
}

h3 {
    text-align:center;
    font-weight:300;
    color:#3C5FA3;
}

.container {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 30px;
}

.clearfix:after {
    visibility:hidden;
    display:block;
    content:"";
    clear:both;
    height:0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container clearfix background">
    <div id="transbox">
        <h3>Some text here</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `clearfix` or anything for this case. All you need is the background opacity. The key here is to give the container:

- `position: relative;`
- `height: <some>px;`

And the `transbox`:

- `position: absolute;`
- `top` and `right` values.

If you want it to be **centered**, it's very easy. Use a dead centre trick like this:

```css
.background {
  background-image: url("https://source.unsplash.com/5OMTuqOM7bI");
}
#transbox {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
h3 {
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #3C5FA3;
}
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 30px;
  position: relative;
  height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container background">
  <div id="transbox">
    <h3>Some text here</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Initial Version**

[image: preview]

**Centered Version**

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

`padding: 0 30px;` is identical to `padding-top: 0; padding-right: 30px; padding-bottom: 0; padding-left: 30px;`

You say:

> *Adding `padding: 20px;`  to `.background` does nothing*

That's because later in your CSS you overwrite this padding in `.container`.

If two or more rules have the same CSS specificity, the one that occurs last wins. Since both selectors have identical specificity, `.container` definitions win over `.background` definitions.